# Using wp-cli to create a .pot file that interprets .twig files as well

Tags: translation

Using the [wp i18n make-pot](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-pot/) I can create a `.pot` file that can interpret `.php` files.
This is the command I use

```
wp i18n make-pot . languages/my-plugin.pot
```

This is good but because I use timber with my wordpress as its template engine, timber uses `.twig` files.
How can I use wp-cli create `.pot` command to look into `.twig` files?
I tried this command

```
wp i18n make-pot . languages/my-plugin.pot --include=*.twig
```

That creates the same `.pot` file that only interpreted `.php` and not `.twig` files as well.

Looking at github issues this is a open issue [ease inheritance in order to support Twig/Timber](https://github.com/wp-cli/i18n-command/issues/52).
Reading this thread I could not really come to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned - it's an open issue so unlikely to have been resolved by any of the solutions in the thread... This seems to be the most likely working solution though

`wp timber make-pot && wp i18n make-pot --merge=twig.pot`

I haven't used timber before but check what file is created with `wp timber make-pot` and ensure that's the one merged into the `i18n` command

The other code examples refer to improvements in the `i18n-command` package itself

**Edit**

Looking at the ticket again this is actually just another "suggested" use case. But there's still hope...

According to [this page on the timber](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/internationalization/) GitHub support there are a few options available to you.

1. Use a tool that supports parsing Twig files to detect all your translations like [Poedit](https://poedit.net/). This will make your `.pot` files and the merge command can be run to work it into the `i18n` function.
2. A nasty twig vs. gettext hack is to add `{#<?php#}` to the top of your twig files. By doing this, gettext will interpret whatever comes next as PHP, and start looking for `__`.
3. [Twig gettext extractor](https://github.com/umpirsky/Twig-Gettext-Extractor) - a special Twig parser for Poedit.
4. There is mention of a gulp script to do this... however the links I followed don't seem to work any more - [this is the original](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1465) ticket for the gulp solution though and can be used as a base if you feel like having a crack at that

Comment: This `wp timber make-pot` returns `'timber' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, it doesn't seem that you need to add timber to PATH, don't even know where to look for it, as timber is installed via composer

Comment: Have edited the answer @Buttered_Toast

Comment: Apologize for the delayed comment. Will check all those resources and let you know.